# Error while deleting columns using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

```
sub column_delete()

dim x as workbook
dim sht1 as worksheet
dim currentColumn as integer
dim columnHeader as String

Set x = Workbooks.Open("Path to the file")
Set sht1 = x.Sheets("Page 1")
*For currentColumn = sht1.UsedRange.Columns.Count To 1 Step -1*

*columnHeader = shtl.UsedRange.Cells(1, currentColumn).Value*

Select Case columnHeader
 Case "Date", "Time", "Header" 
  'Nothing'
 Case Else
  *shtl.Columns(currentColumn).Delete*

End Select
Next

End Sub
```

For all the above highlighted steps i am getting error as Run-time error ‘424’:
Object required.

But i believe i have declared the required object. Sometimes, when i reopen excel the error goes and other time it appears.

Can you please help me with this issue.

P.S : I am a beginner in excel vba.

Comment: `sht1`(with an 'one') is not the same as `shtl` (with a 'L'). Always use `Option Explicit` at the start of module to see those annoying typos.

Comment: @VincentG - good one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always write `Option Explicit` on the top of your module.

Thus, errors like `sht1` and `shtl` will be avoided, as far as you get an error on compile time with the nondefined variable highlighted:

[image]